# Using DirectShow based virtual camera with Electron framework to render content of <div> element

Tags: c++, com, electron, directshow, virtual-webcam

I am trying to build Desktop application using [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) framework which can output content of particular `<div>` element to [DirectShow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/directshow) based virtual camera.

With the help of famous [Viveks virtual camera](https://github.com/roman380/tmhare.mvps.org-vcam) and [Sample Push Source Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/push-source-filters-sample) I am able to create virtual camera which is rendering Desktop in virtual camera.

Now I want to use this virtual camera with electron app to output content of `<div>`. I am not able to figure out what should be approach to achieve this? I guess I have to develop DirectShow Capture Filter which will interact with virtual camera which I am not sure.

What should be approach to render `<div>` content to virtual camera?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/step-2--declare-cvideorenderer-and-derived-classes

It appears you'd need to get the window handle HWND for the Electron window and write to a RECT within that window, similar to how you'd do it with a DirectX swapchain. I'm not sure there's a way specifically to render to an element within the window, but you may be able to expose some variable that your C++ component could read to determine the viewport.